# Parameter and Variable Group selection - YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm having some trouble performing logic within an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline. What I want to do is when two separate selections from my parameters eq true, then the pipeline selects a particular variable group. I have had 'some' success using the following but it doesn't work properly.

```
  - name: environment
    displayName: environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
    - global
    - dev
    - pre
    - perf
    - prod

  - name: deployment_type
    displayName: infrastructure to run
    type: string
    default: sandbox
    values:
    - identity
    - landing-zone
    - management
    - connectivity
    - sandbox
    - services/devops
    - applications/application-demo


  - ${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'global', parameters.deployment_type, 'identity') }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-identity
  - ${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'global', parameters.deployment_type, 'management') }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-management
  - ${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'global', parameters.deployment_type, 'connectivity') }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-connectivity
  - ${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'global', parameters.deployment_type, 'landing-zone') }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-landing-zone
  - ${{ if in(parameters.environment, 'global', parameters.deployment_type, 'sandbox') }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-sandbox
```

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong or if there is a way of fixing the above?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted the logic out now... it was in the documentation to be fair! :)

If anyone else gets stuck with something similar, here's the answer.

```
  - ${{ if and(eq(parameters.environment, 'global'), eq(parameters.deployment_type, 'identity')) }}:
    - group: infrastructure-subscription-identity
```